# How do I call my store? I'm using Extjs 4.2

Tags: extjs, store

I am trying to get the summary of the values in my grid, since the extjs already has a function sum in store, it will be the easiest way, but I'm having a hard time calling the store.

Comment: Do you mean get a reference to the store?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way may be to do `grid.getStore()`. Generally, you can access a store via the `Ext.getStore()` method.

Example: for a store like

```
Ext.define('Commute.store.Routes', {
     autoLoad: true,
     model: 'Commute.model.Route', 
     extend: 'Ext.data.ArrayStore',
     data: [
        [1, 'To Work by bus'],
        [2, 'To Home by bus'],
        [3, 'To Work by bike'],
        [4, 'To Home by bike']
     ],
});
```

you can call `Ext.getStore('Routes')`.